# How to send two files into a single MQ message with different MsgSeqNumber

Tags: ibm-mq

Good Afternoon,

**I'm working from a unix machine.**
I've two XML files and I need to load them into a queue. The two files should be 'considered' a single MQ message.

First, I tried to concatenate the files together and to upload them on a queue with

```
ma01_q -o QueueName -m ManagerQueue -F Filename;
```

However, the receiver of the message didn't succeed to make the distinction between the two files.
He provided me some part of what was expected in the hexadecimal message:

```
...
A GRP 000...
A MSQ 1
...
A MSF 8
...
The content of the first file in hexadecimal
... 
A GRP 000...
A MSQ 2
...
A MSF 24
...
The content of the second file in hexadecimal
```

So according to him, I should use the parameters **GroupId** and **MsgSeqNumber**.
For the first file:

1. Put '**MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP**' in field **MsgFlags** of the message descriptor.
2. Use '**MQPMO_LOGICAL_ORDER**' on the **MQPUT**.
3. Perform the **MQPUT**.

For the second file:

1. Put '**MQMF_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP**'  in field **MsgFlags** of the message descriptor.
2. Use option '**MQPMO_LOGICAL_ORDER**' on the **MQPUT**.
3. Perform the **MQPUT**.

This will automatically generate a '**GroupID**'  and '**MsgSeqNumber**' for each file. Using the flag '**MQMF_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP**' will ensure that the message group is 'closed'.

The two files are one message each but grouped together using MQ "Message Grouping".

Is it possible to do that on unix with **ma01_q** or **qload**?

Comment: Are you using the q/qload that IBM in the past released as IBM MQ SupportPacs MA01 (q) and MO03 (qload) which are no longer releases as SupportPacs and have now had source released on [github](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-q-qload), or are you using the products with commercial support from MQGem Software: [Q](https://www.mqgem.com/q.html) and [QLOAD](https://www.mqgem.com/qload.html)?  Also note that at MQ v9.1 a took that has the functionality of MO03 (qload) was released as part of the core IBM MQ product and called dmpmqmsg.

Comment: Your question suggests you want the files as a single message but then you describe putting them as two different messages. Could you explain why you want them as a single message?

Comment: Good Morning, @JoshMc: we have supportPacs MA01 and MO03 indeed. The version are: ma01_q (v6) and qload is running on v1.9.

Comment: Good Morning @MoragHughson I don't really know. It's part of the requirements I received. The files are linked to each other and should came together. I'm not really familiar with MQ messaging but I guess indeed it's two messages that will be generated but when the GroupID and the MsgSeqNumber are given it means they are part of the same "big" message.

Comment: @spawnkam - yes that makes more sense. The two files are one message *each* but grouped together using MQ "Message Grouping". Suggest you update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither ma01 nor the qload supports creating message groups.

You could use the mqput2 program from support pack ih03. The mqput2 program can use the MQMD header provided in the file. So you would need to add the MQMD to your files, with the desired message group and sequence number details, then use mqput2 to put your files on the queue.

But I think it would be better to write your own program to do this.